How to enable dual channel memory mode on an Asus-WS-Pro-X570-ACE motherboard?
I have an Asus WS-Pro-X570-ACE motherboard, and plug two exact same memory sticks(Hynix,16GB,DDR4,2R*8) onto A2 and B2 slots of it according to the user manual about Enable Dual Channel section 1.4 (page 1-12).
But when I run sysbench memory run in debian12, I got a result that is same with the result when I run it in a single channel mode.
Like this:

sysbench 1.0.20 (using system LuaJIT 2.1.0-beta3)
Running the test with following options: Number of threads: 1
Initializing random number generator from current time
Running memory speed test with the following options:   block size:
1KiB   total size: 102400MiB   operation: write   scope: global
Initializing worker threads...
Threads started!
Total operations: 77184144 (7718000.79 per second)
75375.14 MiB transferred (7537.11 MiB/sec)
General statistics:
total time:                          10.0000s
total number of events:              77184144
Latency (ms):
min:                                    0.00
avg:                                    0.00
max:                                    0.01
95th percentile:                        0.00
sum:                                 3647.56
Threads fairness:
events (avg/stddev):           77184144.0000/0.00
execution time (avg/stddev):   3.6476/0.00

Is there any tricky method I missed?


But when I run sysbench memory run in debian12, I got a result that is same with the result when I run it in a single channel mode.
75375.14 MiB transferred (7537.11 MiB/sec)

A 2-channel DDR4 @ 3200 MT/s system has a theoretical peak memory bandwidth of 64b x 2 x 3.2G / 8 = 51.2 GB/s, but your benchmark only shows 7.5 GB/s, which is 10% of the theoretical peak value. Thus, the benchmark itself is flawed. You're not saturating your peak system memory bandwidth to begin with, so it's the lack of difference is not surprising.
A good memory benchmark should be multithreaded since a single-thread application is generally incapable of saturating the full bandwidth (vectorization can help, but only up to a point). Furthermore, the program's inner loop should ideally be written in a low-level language like assembly, or FORTRAN/C with compiler optimization, so you can put the greatest stress on the CPU and its memory subsystem. There are several reputable and industry-standard memory benchmarks available, including John D. McCalpin's STREAM benchmark, and the built-in memory benchmark included in the tool likwid-bench in LIKWID. Both tools are widely used in scientific and high-performance computing world and were used in many academic research papers.
Thus, please consider using STREAM or likwid-bench to correctly measure your system's memory bandwidth.
STREAM
STREAM is a small C/FORTRAN code written by Dr. John D. McCalpin, and has been used for benchmark supercomputers since the 1990s, today it remains an industry-standard due to its simplicity.
To run a STREAM test, get the source code from https://github.com/jeffhammond/STREAM (this is an unofficial mirror).
git clone https://github.com/jeffhammond/STREAM.git

Compile the C code manually (don't use the Makefile) with:
gcc -fopenmp -O3 -march=native -DSTREAM_ARRAY_SIZE=100000000 stream.c -o stream.100M

The macro STREAM_ARRAY_SIZE controls the allocated array size.
Then run it with:
./stream.100M

By default, OpenMP will run STREAM on all CPU cores. Finally the following result can be obtained:
-------------------------------------------------------------
Function    Best Rate MB/s  Avg time     Min time     Max time
Copy:           42926.6     0.038757     0.037273     0.043436
Scale:          28796.6     0.056992     0.055562     0.060382
Add:            31537.8     0.078600     0.076099     0.086864
Triad:          31400.9     0.079844     0.076431     0.092603
-------------------------------------------------------------

Due to the lack of non-temporal store optimization in GCC, in Scale, Add and Triad tests, the CPU performs Write-Allocate which creates an extra overhead in the memory subsystem that is not measured. To correctly interpret this result, you should multiply the result of Scale by 1.5, and multiply the result of Add and Triad by 1.33. The reason of doing so involves an understanding of CPU's cache, I've already explained it in another answer Expected results of a stream memory bandwidth benchmark here.
For example, in this case:

Copy: 42926.6 x 1.0 = 42926.6 MB/s
Scale: 28796.6 x 1.5 = 43194.9 MB/s
Add: 31537.8 x 1.33 = 41945.3 MB/s
Triad: 31400.9 x 1.33 = 41763.2 MB/s

As you can see, on my machine, I'm getting around 40 GB/s of memory bandwidth in STREAM benchmark in all these tests. This is to be expected, as usable memory bandwidth is usually around 70%-80% of the theoretical memory bandwidth. Note that memory bandwidth is always reported in GB/s by convention, not GiB/s.
Running the system single-channel memory will halve the STREAM speed. Try doing this experiment yourself: Remove one DIMM channel, STREAM results will be reduced by 50. Add the DIMM channel back, the results go up again.
LIKWID
STREAM is a classic, so it's useful to run it for comparison with other people's benchmarks. But it can be error-prone. On desktops it can be okay (as long as you understand the effective of Non-Temporal Stores). But on servers, there are so many pitfalls related to NUMA, compiler, and CPU's write-allocate behavior - which are not automatically handled and can generate misleading results.
So to test CPU memory bandwidth, I prefer the use of LIKWID. Likwid is the Swiss army knife of performance tuning in HPC applications. Its primary use is collecting statistics from low-level hardware performance counters to understand and optimize the performance characteristics of your code. But it also includes a micro-benchmacrk tool called likwid-bench.
First, run make and make install according to LIKWID's official manual. Then, a tool called likwid-bench becomes available. likwid-bench can automatically launch multiple instances of the benchmark programs and pin the process and memory of each instance to its corresponding NUMA node. It also provides many pre-written benchmark kernels (including the equivalent of a STREAM Triad benchmark) in hand-written assembly, allowing accurate and consistent results, such as:
$ likwid-bench -a
copy - Double-precision vector copy, only scalar operations
copy_avx - Double-precision vector copy, optimized for AVX
copy_avx512 - Double-precision vector copy, optimized for AVX-
copy_mem - Double-precision vector copy, only scalar operations but with non-temporal stores
copy_mem_avx - Double-precision vector copy, uses AVX and non-temporal stores
copy_mem_avx512 - Double-precision vector copy, uses AVX-
copy_mem_sse - Double-precision vector copy, uses SSE and non-temporal stores
copy_sse - Double-precision vector copy, optimized for SSE
stream - Double-precision stream triad A(i) = B(i)*c + C(i), only scalar operations
stream_avx - Double-precision stream triad A(i) = B(i)*c + C(i), optimized for AVX
stream_avx512 - Double-precision stream triad A(i) = B(i)*c + C(i), optimized for AVX-
stream_avx512_fma - Double-precision stream triad A(i) = B(i)*c + C(i), optimized for AVX-
stream_avx_fma - Double-precision stream triad A(i) = B(i)*c + C(i), optimized for AVX FMAs
stream_mem - Double-precision stream triad A(i) = B(i)*c + C(i), uses SSE and non-temporal stores
stream_mem_avx - Double-precision stream triad A(i) = B(i)*c + C(i), uses AVX and non-temporal stores
stream_mem_avx512 - Double-precision stream triad A(i) = B(i)*c + C(i), uses AVX-
stream_mem_avx_fma - Double-precision stream triad A(i) = B(i)*c + C(i), optimized for AVX FMAs and non-temporal stores
stream_mem_sse - Double-precision stream triad A(i) = B(i)*c + C(i), uses SSE and non-temporal stores
stream_mem_sse_fma - Double-precision stream triad A(i) = B(i)*c + C(i), uses SSE FMAs and non-temporal stores

Here's an example of using likwid-bench for measuring memory bandwidth using the STREAM Triad benchmark, using AVX, FMA, and non-temporal stores, using 4 instances with each optimally pinned to a NUMA node.
To benchmark a single desktop computer using the STREAM Triad test, run:
$ likwid-bench -t stream_mem_avx_fma -w M0:1GB

The argument M0:1GB means running the test on the first NUMA node of the machine. Since desktop computers only have one NUMA node, this is adequate. For servers, use as many NUMA nodes as the CPU has.
Since the assembly code already uses non-temporal stores for optimization, there's no need to manually correct the likwid-bench result. The likwid-bench result should be very similar with the manually-corrected STREAM result.
For reference, this is a dual-socket Intel Xeon E5-2680 v4 machine with 4-channel DDR4 ECC RDIMM @ 2400 MT/s on each socket, so it should behave like a 8-channel machine. The Cluster-On-Die mode is enabled in BIOS, as a result, each CPU is seen as two NUMA nodes - the CPU's silicon is physically partitioned into 2 parts, each with its own 2-channel memory controller interconnected by bridges between two separate Ring Bus, each with half the cores. The entire machine has 4 NUMA nodes. For NUMA-aware application, this offers the highest memory bandwidth.
$ likwid-bench -t stream_mem_avx_fma -w M0:1GB -w M1:1GB -w M2:1GB -w M3:1GB
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Cycles:                 22089219858
CPU Clock:              2394502471
Cycle Clock:            2394502471
Time:                   9.224973e+00 sec
Iterations:             14336
Iterations per thread:  256
Inner loop executions:  186011
Size (Byte):            3999980544
Size per thread:        71428224
Number of Flops:        85332918272
MFlops/s:               9250.21
Data volume (Byte):     1023995019264
MByte/s:                111002.50
Cycles per update:      0.517719
Cycles per cacheline:   4.141749
Loads per update:       2
Stores per update:      1
Load bytes per element: 16
Store bytes per elem.:  8
Load/store ratio:       2.00
Instructions:           39999805457
UOPs:                   58666381312


Increase the Number of Threads in sysbench?
I'm not familiar with sysbench, but does it allow you to run the memory benchmark with multiple threads. If so, consider redo your own test using as many threads as CPU cores or hardware SMT threads.
